# Looping through items and saving to .xlsx file, only saves the last value using web scraping?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, openpyxl

I am very new to python. Trying to learn as much as I can while doing projects to maintain interest levels.

In the code below, I am trying to scrape information from a website and get all the Company names and address etc into an excel file. I think I need to define how the excel rows and columns need to be assigned for each of the iterations/companies. I am just drawing a blank on how exactly to go about it.

```
import requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook


url = "https://dir.indiamart.com/search.mp?ss=Power+Distribution+Transformers"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
    print("<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (link.get("href"), link.text))


g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "nes"})

c = []
d = []
for item in g_data:
    c.append(item.contents[3].text)
    d.append(item.contents[1].text)
    wb = load_workbook("Trial.xlsx")
    ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
    for i in c:
        ws1["A2"] = i
        wb.save("Trial.xlsx")
        for x in d:
            ws1["B2"] = x
            wb.save("Trial.xlsx")
```

Comment: You keep overwriting the same cells and saving the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests, bs4, re, csv

url = 'https://dir.indiamart.com/search.mp?ss=Power+Distribution+Transformers'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
blocks = soup.find_all('div', class_='lst')

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for b in blocks:
        name = b.find(class_='cnm').get_text(strip=True)
        addr = b.find(class_='clg').get_text(strip=True)
        call = b.find(class_='ls_co phn').find(text=re.compile('\d+')).strip()
        writer.writerow([name, addr, call])
```

out:

```
"Padmavahini Transformers Private Limited, Coimbatore","Saravanampatti, CoimbatoreS. F. No. 353/1, Door No. 7/140, Ruby Matriculation School Road Keeranatham, Saravanampatti,Coimbatore-641035,Tamil Nadu",8071681548
Guru Teg Bahadur Metal Works,"Shimlapuri, LudhianaNo. 1621, Street No. 4, Kwality Road, Near Kwality Chowk Shimlapuri,Ludhiana-141003,Punjab",8079452881
Servokon Systems Ltd.,"Servokon House, New DelhiServokon House, C-13, Radhu Palace Road Opposite Scope Minar,New Delhi-110092,Delhi",8048077499
Muskaan Power Infrastructure Ltd,"Dhandari Kalan, LudhianaSua Road, Industrial Area - C, Dhandari Kalan,Ludhiana-141014,Punjab",8079465606
Tamilnadu Electricals,"Ambattur Industrial Estate, ChennaiNo. 95 - H, (SP) Ambattur Industrial Estate,Chennai-600058,Tamil Nadu",8046073728
L. D. Power Transformers Pvt. Ltd.,"Sector 3, NoidaA-9, Sector- 59, Phase- 3,Noida-201301,Uttar Pradesh",8048111124
Western Electricals (pvt.) Ltd.,"Kaman, PalgharS. No. 6, H. No. 1, ( Part), Behind Shanti Metal, Near Sai Service, Vasai - Kaman Road Sativali Village, Taluka Vasai (E),Palghar-401208,Maharashtra",8071683491
```

You can use CSV file to store data, then open it in Excel. The CSV module is easy to use.

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. Now I need to understand how. :)  Just noticed something, the page has the option to: Show More Results. The url however doesn't change. I was thinking I can simply have a function which automatically changes the url, confused about it.

Comment: @Sid  the csv part or find() part?

Comment: The find() part. It is using the class from the page inspect element, then getting the text using get_text(from the requests library?) strip would remove the tags? I would want to get into the webpage of each company after this and get the contact us info as the number on search page is more or less not useful. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Sid the rest page is rendered by JavaScrip, requests can not handle it, use selenium. and `get_text()` is a method in bs4, strip is used to get rid of whitespace in the text.

Comment: Thanks, I will get onto selenium once I understand the above code completely. :)